# AWS SES: How to get the response for an email request?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SDK for java to send emails. Following is my code -

```
public void sendMessage(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        // Sending the email.
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
        RawMessage rawMessage =
                new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest =
                new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
        SendRawEmailResult result = client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
        log.info("Email sent!");
        log.debug("Email sent with message id: {}",result.getMessageId());
    }
```

Now I want to be able to check if my email was sent or not. I found some documentation stating that SES always returns a response along with the message id, if so how can I extract the response from the message id? If not, then what other ways are possible to get the response?

Answer (score 0):

Try / catch. Do the error handling in the catch block.

```
public void sendMessage(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    // Sending the email.
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
    RawMessage rawMessage =
            new RawMessage(ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest =
            new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage);
   
 try {
    SendRawEmailResult result = client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle error here
  }

}
```

Comment: Tried this, but no ecxeption is thrown even if I use an invalid email id as the recipient

Comment: If it is bounces you are looking for you need to set up an alert. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-bounce-notifications-sns/

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're missing an await command.

I think it should look like this:

```
SendRawEmailResult result = await client.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
```